# Join multiple selectors that are variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to join variables that are cashed selectors?

```
$('.active').each(function(){
  var $a = $(this);
  var $a_h5 = $a.closest('h5');
  var $a_h4 = $a.closest('h4');
});
```

Doesn't work:

```
$('[name=get]').html($($a_h4,$a_h5,$a).map(function() {
  return $(this).html();
}).get().join(', '));
```

Doesn't work:

```
$('[name=get]').html($a_h4.add($a_h5).add($a).map(function() {
  return $(this).html();
}).get().join(', '));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly here...

Comment: @elclanrs I'm trying to join `content of h4` + `content of h5` + `content of .active` and join all these results if there are more than one `.active`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
$('[name=get]').html($($.merge($a_h4,$a_h5,$a)).map(function() {
```